# How to pass custom data in event wxWidgets

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

## Situation

I am currently writing an app with wxPython (wxWidgets for Python).

In this app is displayed a list of conversations, with an "Open conversation" button at the end of each row. Let's call this window "All conversations".

Clicking any one of the buttons calls the function "open_conversation(self, event)", which displays the full conversation.

What I want to do is, at the generation of the window "All conversations", pass some custom data in each "Bind" event or in each "wxButton" object, such as a string (the name of the contact for instance) ; afterwards, when a button is clicked, it will pass said data in the "event" argument, becoming accessible in the function with something like `contact = event.CustomData["recipient"]`.

## Issue

Referring to the [documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a0f30c8fa5583b4a5f661897d63de3b62), I found the "userData" keyword for the "Bind" method, but it looks like it doesn't work in Python.

```py
self.openConversation_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.open_conversation, userData="test")
TypeError: _EvtHandler_Bind() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userData'
```

## Update

I've marked the solution of Rolf of Saxony as correct because it fits my need best, however I'd advise in general to use the custom event system as suggested by VZ.

Comment: You may create a custom event. See [wxPython docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html#custom-event-summary)

Comment: Right, I'll delve into that ; may I assume there is no built-in way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to pass custom data into a `callback` event is to use a `lambda` function.
e.g.

```
import wx

class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, value):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("a"))
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("b"))
        self.btn3 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("No flag"))
        self.btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.btnSizer.Add(self.btn1 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btnSizer.Add(self.btn2 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btnSizer.Add(self.btn3 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,  lambda event: self.OnButton(event, flag="A"))
        self.btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,  lambda event: self.OnButton(event, flag="B"))
        self.btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,  self.OnButton)
        self.SetSizer(self.btnSizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self,event, flag=None):
        if flag:
            print ("Button pressed was "+flag)
        else:
            print ("A button got pressed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    ButtonFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Woo, nice one ! I'll look into that this afternoon and close the thread by tonight if it works !

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion to define a custom event is definitely the right thing to do, in general, but if all you need is just a single string and/or number, you can also repurpose the existing `wxCommandEvent` class and use its `SetString()` or `SetInt()` methods.

Comment: Ok, good to know !
For large apps I can understand writting custom events, however in my case, just passing a single string/int is enough, so I'll look into the functions you mentioned.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in a full C++ exemple, here it is:

```cpp
#include <wx/wx.h>

struct CustomData final : public wxClientData {
    std::string myString;
};

struct MyApp final : public wxApp {
    bool OnInit() final;
};

struct MyWindow final : public wxFrame {
    static constexpr int ID_MY_BUTTON{ 42 };

                MyWindow();
                MyWindow( MyWindow const & ) = delete;
    MyWindow &  operator=( MyWindow const & ) = delete;
    void        OnButton( wxCommandEvent & event );

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

bool MyApp::OnInit() {
    MyWindow * const window{ new MyWindow() };
    window->Show( true );
    return true;
}

MyWindow::MyWindow() {
    wxButton * const myButton{ new wxButton( this, ID_MY_BUTTON ) };
    CustomData * const myData{ new CustomData() };
    myData->myString = "Hello World!";
    myButton->SetClientObject( myData );
}

void MyWindow::OnButton( wxCommandEvent & event ) {
    wxEvtHandler const * const eventObject{ static_cast< wxEvtHandler * >( event.GetEventObject() ) };
    if ( eventObject == nullptr ) {
        return;
    }

    CustomData const * const myData{ static_cast< CustomData const * >( eventObject->GetClientObject() ) };
    if ( myData == nullptr ) {
        return;
    }

    std::cout << myData << "\n";
}

wxIMPLEMENT_APP( MyApp );

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE( MyWindow, wxFrame )
EVT_BUTTON( MyWindow::ID_MY_BUTTON, MyWindow::OnButton )
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
```

No need to delete the `CustomData` instance, wxWidgets takes care of it.
And the key steps here are:

- Inherit `wxClientData`class to attach your data
- Call `wxEvtHandler::SetClientObject()` with your heap-allocated custom data object
- In the callback, retreive the button with `wxCommandEvent::GetEventObject()`
- Retreive your custom data with `wxEvtHandler::GetClientObject()`